# Logistical Errors in Mastermind Game

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some background: MasterMind® is a code-breaking game invented in the early 1970’s by Mordechai Meirovitz. In this game,
one player – the code master – is responsible for generating a code that consists of a sequence of four colors. A
second player – the code breaker – attempts to guess the code. After each guess, the code master provides
feedback about the guess. Specifically, the code master will tell the code breaker how many colors were correct
and how many of the colors are in the correct position. The code-breaker continues to guess the code until they
are able to successfully break the code. The code breaker’s “score” is the number of guesses that it takes break
the code.

The objective of this program is to:

1. Define the valid colors.
2. Use the valid colors to generate the secret code.
3. As long as I haven’t guessed the code yet: Ask the user to guess; update the number of guesses. Make sure the guess is valid
4. Determine the number of correct Colors
5. Determine the number of correct Locations
6. Provide this feedback to the code breaker
7. Report the final score to the user

I have only confidently gotten through steps 1 & 2. My question is how I can get the `isValidGuess` function to determine that there is only `validColors` present. As it is written right now, the function is not incorporating the `validColors` parameter, and I am not entirely sure why. For each function, there is a brief explanation of what the function *should* be doing.

-Note- I do not want someone to write the entire code for me, just to help me with the `isValidGuess` function.

```
import random 
validColors = ["R", "G", "B", "Y", "O", "P"]

def generateCode(validColors):
    #input: takes a string that represents validColors
    #action: builds a string of length 4; each character is picked at random
    #       from the validColors
    #return:  a string of length 4 representing the codemaster's secretCode
    secretCode = random.sample(validColors, 4)
    return secretCode

def isValidGuess(guess, validColors):
    #input: guess and validColors as strings
    #action: ensures that the guess is the right length and only contains
    #       valids colors
    #return: boolean value to isValidGuess
    isValidGuess = False 
    if len(guess) != 4:
        print("Invalid, guess again.")
    elif len(guess) == 4:
        isValidGuess = True 
    return isValidGuess 

#def correctLocationCount(secretCode, guess):
    #input: secretCode and guess as strings
    #action: character by character comparison of the two strings and
    #       updates a counter every time they match
    #return: the counter

#def correctColorCount(secretCode, guess, validColors):
    #input: secretCode, guess, and valid colors as strings
    #action: looks at each valid color and counts how many times that color
    #       appears in the code and how many times it appears in the guess
    #       Compare these counts to determine how many colors were guessed
    #return: the count


def masterMind():
     generateCode(validColors)
     guess = input("What is your guess: ")
     result = isValidGuess(guess, validColors)
     while result == False:
        guess = input("What is your guess: ")
        result = isValidGuess(guess, validColors)
```

Comment: Unrelated to the color question you're asking: Are you sure that your `isValidGuess` function is supposed to loop and prompt for a new guess when it sees the one it was given is invalid? I'd expect it should just return `False` in that situation (and let the calling code do the looping). You'll have problems with the current code because your new `guess` value won't be accessible to the calling code.

Comment: This is true, I didn't even think about that. I edited the loop into an if statement, but I'm still running into the issue of `isValidGuess` not recognizing the `validColors` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if each color in `code` is also in `validColors`. The most idiomatic way of doing it in Python is by using the builtin `all` function with a generator expression: `all(color in validColors for color in guess)`.

An alternative approach (which might be easier for a new programmer to understand) would be to use an explicit loop:

```
for color in guess:
    if color not in validColors:
        # do whatever is appropriate for an invalid color here (e.g. return False)
```

You might need to reverse the logic of your current `isValidGuess` variable (have it default to `True` and get reset to `False` if the guess proves to be invalid). Or you could get rid of that variable and just `return False` immediately whenever you find something invalid (and `return True` at the end of the function if nothing has proven disqualifying).

Note that my doesn't check for duplicate colors in the guess. If that should not be allowed you will probably need a separate check for it, probably using a `set`. If you make `validColors` into a set too, you can check everything in one very compact expression:

```
def isValidGuess(guess, validColors):
    valid_set = set(validColors) # if validColors was already a set this would be unnecessary
    guess_set = set(guess)
    return len(guess) == len(guess_set) == 4 and guess_set.issubset(valid_set)
```